# запрос count вместе с основным запросом

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Есть SQL запрос, который берет определенное кол-во записей на странице, допустим с 20й по 30ю. И на каждой странице дополнительно нужен общий счетчик, допустим кол-во записей. Получается надо делать запроса, первый с выборкой записей, второй с счетчиком. Можно как то объединить запросы?

p.s.

```
//
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1 ".$myParam." ORDER BY `code` DESC LIMIT 20,30
SELECT count(*) WHERE 1 ".$myParam."
```

я понимаю, что есть другие решения допустим кол-во посчитать раз и потом только переменную передавать, и это правильнее, но меня интересует именно запрос

Comment: Как я понимаю, тут достаточно добавить подзапрос к основному запросу. `SELECT (SELECT count(*) WHERE 1 ".$myParam."
) as rowCount, * FROM table WHERE 1 ".$myParam." ORDER BY code DESC LIMIT 20,30`

Comment: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ...` и `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`. См. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows PS. Результат второго запроса можно сохранить в сессионной локальной переменной. PPS. Некорректно работает при UNION DISTINCT.

Comment: @Tivyram - синтаксис верный? я даже запрос в упрощенном виде исполнить не могу SELECT (SELECT count(*) ) as `rowCount`, * FROM `user`. @Akina - просто думал что за столько лет стандартную задачку упростили, что бы сессию не использовать, что кстати не очень верно, т.к. придется обновлять переменную

Comment: Mike - Оно самое. Спс